# Partitioning for ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

My PC has only one operating system installed: Windows 7 on single partition C:.

Is it necessary to partition it before installing Ubuntu alongside with Windows 7 or can I simply install Ubuntu in the same partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu inside your partition C:, but this is Ubuntu-specific mechanism (Wubi) and it is not normal operating system installation scenario, so I would not recommend it.

However, it is quite easy to shrink your C: partition and create partitions for Ubuntu during Ubuntu installation. Boot your PC with Ubuntu installation disk, and when asked by installer about partitions, choose "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" or something like that. Then you choose how much Windows C: partition should be shrinked and then creating Ubuntu partitions on the obtained free disk space is done automatically.

Comment: Hi Mikolaj.... My system is already with Windows 7 so can I just proceed with the same procedure mentioned by you using a bootable pendrive to install Ubuntu????

Comment: @user292135 Yes, installation procedure is exactly the same, regardless if installer is run from CD or from USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't install two OS's on the same partition.
As far i know when trying to boot from USB or CD to install Ubuntu it will allow you to partition it into two different sizes.

Comment: -1; this is not true in the case of Ubuntu; Wubi installer allows to install Ubuntu on the same partition as Windows.